# Erase empty cells in an array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I paste an array in a column, the problem is that it leaves some cells in the column empty. How can I erase those cells in the column?

This is what I have:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Worksheets("Info").Range("A1").Select
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim iLastRow As Long
    iLastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim arrmatrix() As String

     ReDim arrmatrix(1 To iLastRow, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To iLastRow
    Range("A2").Cells(i, 1).Select
    If Selection.Offset(0, 11) = "Pi emitida" Then
    arrmatrix(i, 1) = Range("A2").Cells(i, 1).Value
    End If
    Next i
    Worksheets("Inicio").Range("G4:G1000000").ClearContents

    Worksheets("Inicio").Range("G4").Resize(UBound(arrmatrix, 1)).Value =     arrmatrix()

end sub
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish nor why you need a `Worksheet_Change` event macro for this. Could you elaborate your description to include what you are trying to do and possibly *why* you want to do it?

Comment: if you really don't want empty value, you can check if Range("A2").Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" before doing arrmatrix(i, 1) = Range("A2").Cells(i, 1).Value. Declare a new Long and increment it each time the condition is fulfilled to redim arrmatrix at the end of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your sample code.

1. Hopefully, this is on the **Info** worksheet's code sheet. You should not be attempting to `.Activate` another worksheet from the `Worksheet_Change` event macro.
2. It isn't clear why you need this in a `Worksheet_Change` event macro. As-is, this will run any time a value anywhere in the worksheet is added/modified/deleted. That sounds like overkill since the only two columns that determine the outcome are columns A and L.
3. The [ReDim statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w8k3cys2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can be used with *Preserve* to expand the array but it can only redimension the last rank.

This modification does not rely on selecting or activating the worksheet(s) before processing them. The *arrmatrix* array is expanded as needed so you do not end up with blank values in the array.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A:A, L:L")) Is Nothing Then
        On Error GoTo Fìn
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Dim i As Long, n As Long
        Dim arrmatrix As Variant
        ReDim arrmatrix(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
        For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            If Cells(i, 12).Value = "Pi emitida" Then
                n = n + 1
                ReDim Preserve arrmatrix(1 To 1, 1 To n)
                arrmatrix(1, n) = Cells(i, 1).Value
            End If
        Next i
        With Worksheets("Inicio")
            .Range("G4:G" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
            .Range("G4").Resize(UBound(arrmatrix, 2), 1) = Application.Transpose(arrmatrix)
        End With
    End If

Fìn:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

This will only run when a value in column A or column L is added/changed/deleted.

Since I've been expanding and populating the last rank, I used `Application.Transpose` to reorient the data before I stuffed it back into the **Inicio** worksheet.

Comment: I'm afraid that I cannot make sense of the conditions you've added. *Pi emitida* comes into the new conditions as well as the original conditions and I cannot determine the hierarchy for the final *And hoy - Cells(j, 12).Value >= 0* since in all other situations Cells(j, 12) is text. It would be best if you edited your original question to include these and offer what you've done to add these new situations yourself.

Comment: I made a new question with my problem, to make it simpler