# Custom User Function (UDF) and Dynamic Ranges

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a Custom User Function (UDF) that returns an array. I use it in an Array Formula on a large range of cells.
The length of the returned array is dependent on the function parameters.
This works great except one thing: When the length of the returned array is smaller than the range defined for the array-formula, the "out-of-range" entries are all set to `#N/A`.

Is there a way to either obtain the array-formula range inside the custom user function (so, if needed, I could prepare a larger array to return), or alternatively return some kind of an iterator (instead of the array) which is not limited in size and would return `""` in case of out-of-range?

Comment: Use [ReDim Preserve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w8k3cys2.aspx) to build your array as you feed it values. For an example you could refer to my answer here: [Erase empty cells in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29930523/erase-empty-cells-in-an-array/29931503#29931503).

Comment: Could you show your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pretty dumb example......a UDF to return the first **7** primes in column form:

```
Public Function Primes()
'
'   Array UDF to return the first 7 primes
'
    Dim rN As Long, ary(1 To 7) As Long
    Dim tdim As Long, i As Long
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction

    rN = Application.Caller.Rows.Count
    tdim = wf.Max(rN, 7)
    ReDim bry(1 To tdim, 1 To 1)

    ary(1) = 1
    ary(2) = 3
    ary(3) = 5
    ary(4) = 7
    ary(5) = 11
    ary(6) = 13
    ary(7) = 17

    For i = 1 To 7
        bry(i, 1) = ary(i)
    Next i

    If tdim > 7 Then
        For i = 8 To tdim
            bry(i, 1) = ""
        Next i
    End If
    Primes = bry
End Function
```

The UDF detects how many cells it has to fill and if that value exceeds **7**, the balance is filled with blanks.

Comment: Perfect. All I needed was `Application.Caller.Rows.Count`.